# The set of numbers not representable as a sum of distinct elements of $\{1, 10, 11, 100, 101, \ldots\}$

Tags: number-theory

Let $S = \{1, 10, 11, 100, 101, 110, 111, 1000\dots\}$ the set of all base $10$ positive integers composed of only $1$s and $0$s.
Let $A$ be the set of all positive integers that cannot be expressed as a sum of different elements of $S$.
Prove that $A$ has only a finite number of elements.

I solved this problem like $4$ years ago, but I don't remember the proof. I do remember I proved every number greater than $10^{19}$ (or was it $10^{38}$?) aren't part of $A$.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138968/discussion-on-question-by-mateo-bozzi-does-a-have-a-finite-number-of-elements).

Answer (score 2):

As you remembered, every member $\ge10^{19}$ is not in $A$.

##### Lemma on the partition of a multiset into sets

**Lemma**: Suppose there are $n$ colors, $1,\cdots,n$. There are $a_i$ balls in color $i$ for $1\le i\le n$, where $1\le|a_i|\le n$. Then we can partition the balls into groups such that each group has no duplicate colors and no two groups are the same, i.e., for any two groups, there is some color that appears exactly in one of two groups.

**Proof**. $n=1$ is trivial.
As induction hypothesis, suppose the lemma is true for $n-1$. Consider the case of $n\ge2$. WLOG, let $a_1\ge\cdots\ge a_n$. There are three cases.

- $a_n=1$. Select the ball in color $n$ and one ball in each color that appears at least twice as a group.
- $a_n=2$. Select one ball of each color as a group. Select the other ball in color $n$ as a group.
- $a_n\ge3$. Select one ball of each color as a group. For each color $i\lt a_n$, select one ball in color $n$ and one ball in color $i$ as a group.

In all cases, each group we have formed has a ball in color $n$ and no repeated colors. Together, they contain all balls in color $n$ (and some other balls). Among the remaining balls, there are at least one ball and at most $n-1$ balls in each color other than $n$. We can use the induction hypothesis. $\quad\checkmark$

##### Any number $\ge 10^{19}$ is not in $A$

Let $10^{i-1}$ correspond to a ball in color $i$ for all $i\ge1$. Accordingly, each number in $S$ corresponds to a group of balls without repeated colors. For example, $100110=10^1 + 10^2 + 10^5$ corresponds to a ball in color $2$, a ball in color $3$ and a ball in color $6$.

Given number $t\ge 10^{19}$, we have
$$t= d_010^0 + d_110^1 + \cdots d_{n}10^n$$ where $19\le n$, $0\le d_i\le9$, $1\le d_{n}$.

Replacing one $10^n$ by $10\cdot10^0 + 9\cdot10^1 + 9\cdot10^2+ \cdots + 9\cdot10^{n-1}$, we have
$$t= (d_0+10)10^0 + (d_1+9)10^1 + (d_2+9)10^2+ \cdots + (d_{n-1} + 9)10^{n-1} + (d_n-1)10^n$$

Let $t$ correspond to the following balls.

- $d_0+ 10$ balls in color $1$,
- $d_{i-1}+9$ balls in color $i$ for $2\le i\le n$, and
- $d_n-1$ balls in color $n+1$.

If $d_n\gt1$, since the number of balls of any color from $1$ to $n+1$ is at least $1$ and at most $9+10=19\le n+1$, we can apply the lemma to these balls with $n+1$ colors, thus expressing $t$ as a sum of different elements of $S$.
Otherwise $d_n=1$, there is no ball in color $n+1$. We can apply the lemma to these balls with colors from $1$ to $n$, thus expressing $t$ as a sum of different elements of $S$ still.

Hence $t\not \in A$. $\quad\checkmark$

##### In fact, any number $\ge 129615$ is not in $A$

```
from itertools import product

def print_all_impossible_numbers(size):
    """Print all numbers in A that is less than 10 ** size"""

    # if size = 3, S is [1, 10, 11, 100, 101, 110, 111]
    S = [int("".join(p)) for p in product("01", repeat=size)]
    S.remove(0)
    print(S)

    # possible[j] will be whether j can be expressed as
    # the sum of some numbers in S
    possible = [False] * (10 ** size)
    possible[0] = True
    for summand in S:
        for j in range(len(possible) - summand - 1, -1, -1):
            possible[j + summand] |= possible[j]

    # A is the list of all numbers less than 10**size that cannot
    # be expressed as the sum of some numbers in S.
    A = [i for i in range(len(possible)) if not possible[i]]
    print(len(A), A)
    print(f"the maximum number in A that is less than {len(possible)} is {max(A)}")


for size in range(1, 8):
    print_all_impossible_numbers(size)
# the maximum number in A that is less than 100000 is 97513
# the maximum number in A that is less than 1000000 is 129614
# the maximum number in A that is less than 10000000 is 129614
```

The Python program above prints out all numbers in $A$ less than some limits. It should help you believe that $A$ contains 25618 numbers with maximum 129614.

$$\begin{aligned}
&2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 13, 14,\\
&15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 23, 24, 25, 26,\\
&27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36,\\
&\cdots\\
&118504, 118514, 118515, 118551, 118614, 119255, 119264, 119472, 119515, 119525\\
&119526, 119562, 119614, 119624, 119625, 119652, 120484, 121495, 121594, 124961\\
&125195, 125951, 126061, 126072, 126194, 126270, 127062, 127260, 129515, 129614.
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: Is it possible that in your answer it should be $d_{n}=1$ instead of $d_{n+1}\geq 1$ and $d_n\geq 2$ instead of $a_{n+1}$?

Comment: @JoelAdler Thanks for pointing out my typos. Updated.